# FATAL ERROR when trying to run my app using S5, Marshmallow

Tags: listview, android-arrayadapter

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hyungmin.letsgo3, PID: 9000
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9b
   at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1468)
   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5050)
   at com.example.hyungmin.letsgo3.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:88)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1841)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<listData> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        items.add(new listData("hong" + R.drawable.like, i + 155));
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```